# Conversion byte decimal to byte bcd

Tags: java, delphi, bcd

I need to convert a Delphi function to Java function. This function convert a byte decimal to byte bcd:

```
function ByteToBCD(Number : byte) : byte;
begin
    result:= ((Number div 10) shl 4) or (Number mod 10);
end;
```

Comment: `div` is `/`, `shl` is `<<` and `or` is `|`. A bigger problem is that there is no unsigned byte type in Java. What type do you want to use? Do you know any Java? Or is it Delphi that you don't understand? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Also, could you please ask a direct question. Here you've just told us that you have some job to do and left us to work out what your question is. I hope you aren't just hoping we'll do it all for you. We prefer to help people that are keen to learn.

Comment: I don´t want anyone solve anything for me. I just need an little explanation of conversion with bcd and a relationship between the operators used in Delphi and Java, just as you did in parts.

Comment: Please state that in the question. Oh, I see I missed `mod` being `%`. Of course both languages are well documented and there operators are well known. It would be better if you read the docs first, and then asked for clarification of anything that you don't understand. As presented, one might suspect you of being lazy. Show us that you are not by adding what you know to the question, and asking a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
public static int byteToBCD(byte b) {
    assert 0 <= b && b <= 99; // two digits only.
    return (b / 10 << 4) | b % 10;
}
```

It is not clear what you are stuck on but it the answer is trivia.

Comment: byte is unsigned in Delphi. I think you need to tackle that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is assumed the value is between 0 and 99 in the original code.  If the value is not exactly 2 digits i.e. 100 or more, we have a problem whether we consider signed or unsigned.

Comment: The user might be confused to find negative values though. They should be ready for that.